# how to make button in leftside of UItoolbar in iphone

Tags: iphone

How can I make a button that is placed in the left side of a UItoolbar on the iPhone?

Comment: Please accept some answers to your previous questions or people will not be motivated to help you. If you are satisfied with an answer, click the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example, you need something like this.

```
    UIBarButtonItem *fixedCenter = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    fixedCenter.width = 80.0f;
    UIBarButtonItem *fixedLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    fixedLeft.width = 40.0f;

    UIBarButtonItem *left = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(moveBack:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *right = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(moveForward:)];

    [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fixedLeft, flex, left, fixedCenter, right, flex, action, nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two UIBarButtonItems. One will be your button and one a flexible space that will take up as much space in the bar as it can after placing all items. Depending on the order you set the items, the button will appear at the very left or right. If you add the space first and then the button(s), all buttons are aligned right. The other way around, your button will be placed at the very left.

Try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourMethod:)];


[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftButton, flexibleSpace, nil]];
[flexSpace release];
[leftButton release];
```