# Iphone Uitoolbar next button

Tags: iphone, ios4

Here is what I did, this is a dynamic questionary application;

-Created a UINavigationBased application

-Created some new UIVIewController subclasses with their xib's and designed them.

-I opened mainwindow.xib and set the navigationcontroller to has a navigation bar and a toolbar in black.

-So now when I switch back and forth between views by pushing them with the navigation controller I can see that shared toolbar and a navigationbar in every page with a backbutton, which is cool.

some of my uiviews are tableviews and some are textboxes

What I want is I want to put a "next" button on that toolbar and be able to go through my views but not with getting the row tap. With each next click I will decide which view to push.

How can I put this "shared" button? and in which class can I define its functionality? also I want to make it sometimes invisible for instance on first page and on last page of questionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every page that you want to have a next button add this in the init or viewDidLoad

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next"
                                                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                       target:self 
                                                                       action:@selector(pushNextView)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
        [rightButton release];
```

Now just implement pushNextView method to push what ever view you want

```
-(void)pushNextView{
  //push next view
}
```

**Edit**

By specifying the target of your rightButton to AppDelegate (right now it points to self) you can setup the pushNextView method in your AppDelegate and manage all your views there.

Comment: tnx it works but the button is on the navigation bar I want it on the tool bar and be able to customize its color and place

Comment: also could you tell me how can I setup my method in appdelegate?

Comment: My friend I now feel that I am writing this application with you if not for you :-)

Comment: Just use `[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rightButton, nil]];` for more info read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038797/how-to-make-button-in-leftside-of-uitoolbar-in-iphone) and answer

Comment: feelings are mutual my friend :) but lets say with me..there is any one around to ask anything, other than this site..